# Как обрезать текст в input?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так чтобы текст в input обрезался следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Взять строку, вырезать часть символов, на их место поставить ... и вернуть в инпут. Или что то конкретное не получается?

Comment: Вообще нет идей как это сделать

Comment: Приведи пример строк (нескольких) "до" и "после" обрезания...

Answer (score 0):

```js
const new_string = 'qwertyuiop[asdfghjkl'
const final_string = f'{new_string[:10]}...{new_string[-10:]}'

console.log(final_string)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @tchaikovski, а не могли бы вы показать это должно выглядит в разметке, я просто только начал учить JS и Html, слабо понимаю

Comment: в js не знаю - я ответил как сделать на python - посмотри тему про срезы

Comment: Попробовал запустить это в консоли браузера - не работает

Comment: @tchaikovski Почему на python, а не на ассемблере или на любом другом языке?